# Eclipse: How to get full filepath from error "Failed to load JNI shared library"?

Tags: eclipse, jvm, java-native-interface, shared, filepath

Something has gone wrong with my java set-up on my computer, obviously, but I can't figure out what it is until I get some more info.

When I try to run Eclipse, it give me an error:

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Eclipse\1234\tools\jdk1.5.0_14\bin\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"
```

I want to know how to find out what the rest of that filepath is.  "\bin..\jre\" doesn't help me much.  I suspect that it's 2 paths concatenated, but I'm not sure.

I've tried running Eclipse from the command line, but the error shows up only in the popup window.

Also, where does the JNI path get set, anyway?

I've looked at my JAVA_HOME environment variable, but it only contains "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin".

This JNI-path-corruption... thing happened after I ran an installer -- nope, no uninstaller :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\Eclipse\1234\tools\jdk1.5.0_14\bin\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

> I want to know how to find out what the rest of that filepath is. "\bin..\jre\" doesn't help me much. I suspect that it's 2 paths concatenated, but I'm not sure.

That is the full path. On all file systems that I've used ".." indicates the parent directory (i.e. up one directory). So the path refers to:

```
C:\Eclipse\1234\tools\jdk1.5.0_14\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

As for how eclipse has decided on trying to use this path, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

your `JAVA_HOME` settings are wrong , as `JAVA_HOME` should point to the directory just above bin , and `in the bin directory` java executable files e.g. java.exe , javac.exe , appletviewer.exe `must exist`.

For example, if on my computer `java.exe` is in `D:\JAVA7\bin` directory my `JAVA_HOME` will be `D:\JAVA7`